# Lost the information in the menu bar/panel in Intellij IDEA on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea

Previously I had information about the path to my project and which project I currently had opened in Intellij, but that information seems to have vanished. How can I get it back?

Excuse my Gimp skills, but here I where I mean: [image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same version of Ubuntu and I can see correctly the project information in IntelliJ. The only case that this info is hidden is when lost the windows focus, behavior that is normal I thing.

You can try to see in IntelliJ logs to find a problem related with this. The logs are saved in /home/${username}/.${idea_version}/system/log

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look at those logs when I'm back at work. And just to clarify for others: I don't have this information even though the program is in focus.